# Deploy Symfony API on Apache - routes not found

Tags: php, api, apache, symfony, deployment

I tried to deploy a Symfony API with apache on port 8000. I can access the index.php (Symfony default page), but when I tried a route like http://{{ my_ip_adress }}:8000/api/users, I have a 404 error.

**Apache file.conf**

```
Listen 8000
<VirtualHost *:{{ http_port }}>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/{{ http_host }}
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/{{ http_host }}>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex ./app/public/index.php 
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase ./

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ./app/public/index.php

    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

It's my first deployment, so I don't understand how Apache works yet.

Comment: please check the ./public/.htaccess file in your symfony app if there might be redundant/concurring directives, also your Directory directive must point to the public folder and not the root of the symfony app

Comment: thanks you for your answer, I checked and don't have another .htaccess , I changed my directory directive but still don't work..